# How to use the inverse function theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have a function $F (x, y) = (x^2+y^2, xy)$ and I need to show that it has an inverse. How do I find the inverse of this function using the inverse function theorem? I have not learned this before in all of my math classes and I just need some brushing up on how to use it.

Thank you for your assistance.

edit: On the set $\{(x, y) : −x < y < x\}$.

Comment: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~tvogel/410/sect116.pdf  may this help

Comment: Thank you for the resource...but it does not have what I want. I want to know how to do get the inverse of this vector function.

Comment: Can anyone show me how to calculate the inverse of this vector function on the given set?

Comment: is not this mentioned in your calculus book? or  is it your own problem?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem  look  tha site,there is given formula for finding inverse

Comment: No, I am helping one of my relatives with the inverse function theorem...the theorem is found in her foundations of analysis book by Taylor. She doesn't understand the notation that is in the book and I am trying to help her; however, it has been a while since I have done the implicit function theorem. how can I find the inverse for this function? I took the jacobian of this function and found it is invertible if X does not equal -y or +y. Then I took the inverse of this matrix to find the jacobian of the inverse. I just need to show how to find the inverse of the above function using the thm.

Comment: in wikipedia there is given  formula for this ,i will add  as answer  picture and please see if this is enough

Comment: What is the general way to find the inverse function for

1. A single variable function
2. a vector valued function
3. a multivariate function

Comment: Showing a function has an inverse is MUCH easier than calculating the inverse (which is not possible in general)

Comment: that is what i have said, for single value   function is  easy to find inverse(not always)but condition for existence inverse of given function is  described on wikipedia

Comment: I posted a set

On the set
{(x, y) : −x < y < x} find the inverse function F
−1
and identify its
domain

Comment: not to  try somebody to force do it.wait  for answer  even tommorow   or after  2 day.but wait please

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Comment: you are welcome.this site is very great for find solution of mathematical problems.but sometimes if problem is  complex ,time is required for others  to find solution,if problem is easy,then it takes  1-5 minute for answer

Answer (score 8):

For $F(x,\, y) = (x^2+y^2,\; xy)$ denote
$$\begin{cases}u = x^2+y^2, \\
v = xy \end{cases}$$
Then
$$\begin{cases}
u+2v=(x+y)^2, \\
u-2v=(x-y)^2 
\end{cases} $$
On the given set $\{(x, y):\;\; −x < y < x \} $ we have $$ x+y>0,\;\;x-y>0, \quad J_F(x,\, y)=2(x^2-y^2)\ne{0},$$ therefore $F$ is invertible and 
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y=\sqrt{u+2v}, \\
x-y=\sqrt{u-2v} 
\end{cases}$$
Thus
$$\begin{cases}
2x=\sqrt{u+2v}+\sqrt{u-2v},\\
2y=\sqrt{u+2v}-\sqrt{u-2v}.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I get how you subbed U and V...but how dothe first two equations imply the second equations?

Comment: he used  rule  $(x+y)^2$  equal to $x^2+2*x*y+y^2$,because  $u=(x+y)^2$ and  $v=x*y$,then it became easy

Comment: $u+2v=x^2+y^2+2xy=(x+y)^2,\;\;u-2v=x^2+y^2-2xy=(x-y)^2$

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 5):

The function
$$F:\quad  \Omega\to{\mathbb R}^2,\qquad  (x,y)\mapsto (u,v):=(x^2+y^2,xy)$$
has an inverse for suitably chosen $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ **not** because of the inverse function theorem, but because you are able to compute this inverse explicitly, as has been done in M. Strochyk's answer. Note that to arrive at the formulae
$$F^{-1}:\quad(u,v)\mapsto (x,y)=\left({\sqrt{u+2v}+\sqrt{u-2v}\over2},{\sqrt{u+2v}-\sqrt{u-2v}\over2}\right)$$
no checking of Jacobians was necessary. In addition we have a clear picture of the domain of $F^{-1}$ corresponding to the given $\Omega$.

The inverse function theorem is needed for theoretical considerations, and in cases where the inverse $F^{-1}$ cannot be expressed in terms of known functions. It is a purely local theorem: Given a point $(x_0,y_0)$ with $F(x_0,y_0)=:(u_0,v_0)$ it guarantees the existence of a "window" $U$ with center $(x_0,y_0)$ such that the restriction $F_{loc}:=F\restriction U$ has an inverse $F^{-1}_{loc}:\ F(U)\to U$ which is again differentiable. The essential technical condition is the nonvanishing of the Jacobian of $F$ at $(x_0,y_0)$. The theorem doesn't tell you what the "maximal domain" of this local inverse could be.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

when you calculate jacobian matrix and found value p,where this matrix's determinant is not zero,there maybe you could you this formula. i would be happy if it helps you.also  you could check  all formula in wikipedia's site
.for single variable .let suppose that

$y=\sqrt{x}$

and   let us replace  places for x and y,or we get
$x=\sqrt{y}$

from which
$y=x^2$

Comment: Eh? how does it help?

Comment: for single variable,i have  put answer,but maybe for multivariable  we are just finding numerical  solution.let us wait for  others

Comment: You just do that by switching around X and Y...and solving for Y. I know about that. how do I do it for a vector valued function?

Comment: that what i have said.because  wikipedia is concentrated on numerical methods,maybe for  vector  value function you are finding  not inverse of function,but  value at  inverse of this function using   jacobian matrix

Comment: I am not given a point to evaluate at.

Comment: @JonnyQuiznos you should  wait  for answers. maybe they  are thinking or they are trying to find solutions,please wait for  them,actually if it is new for you,then  you might need really to wait,if it  is   from professor,then you could ask  him