# Inverse of stereographic projection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, stereographic-projections

I am trying to compute the inverse of

$$f(\theta,\phi) = \left(\frac{\cos\theta \sin\phi}{1-\cos\phi}, \frac{\sin\theta \sin\phi}{1-\cos\phi}\right)$$ but I lack some basic knowledge on how I can do that. Could please provide some guidance?

Thank you in advance.

*Edit*:
Following `@peek-a-boo's` comment (and `M. Strochyk's` [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/345510)), I have tried the following. For

$$f:\quad  (\Theta,\Phi) \to (X,Y),\qquad  (\theta,\phi)\mapsto (x,y):=\left(\frac{\cos\theta \sin\phi}{1-\cos\phi}, \frac{\sin\theta \sin\phi}{1-\cos\phi}\right),$$
and setting $$x = \frac{\cos \theta \sin \phi}{1 - \cos \phi},$$ and $$y = \frac{\sin \theta \sin \phi}{1 - \cos\phi},$$ we have

$$x^2+y^2 = \frac{1 +\cos \phi}{1 - \cos \phi},$$ and

$$\frac{y^2}{x^2} = \frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta}.$$

Combining the last two equations we obtain

$$x = \left|\cos \theta \right| \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \theta}{1-\cos \theta}} ,$$ and

$$y = \left|\sin \theta \right| \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \theta}{1-\cos \theta}},$$ which finally leads

$$f^{-1}:\quad(x,y)\mapsto (\theta,\phi) = \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \theta}{1-\cos \theta}}\left(\left|\cos \theta \right| , \left|\sin \theta \right|\right)$$

Comment: For the inverse, you certainly need to make restrictions on $\theta$ and $\phi$. Once you do so, notice that if you call $(x,y)$ the output, then $x^2+y^2 = 1 + \cos \phi$ (use the fact $\sin^2\phi = 1-\cos^2\phi = (1-\cos\phi)(1+\cos\phi)$). Next, notice that (whenever the division makes sense) $y/x = \tan\theta$. So, if you restrict the domain sufficiently, you can invert these trig functions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo thanks for the interest. I used you comment to post an answer to my question. Is it possible to check the validity of what I have tried? Thanks again.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Actually, $x^2+y^2=\cot^2(\phi/2)$ (not $1+\cos\phi$). Using $\sin^2\phi=1-\cos^2\phi$ would instead yield $x^2+y^2=(1+\cos\phi)/(1-\cos\phi)$.

Comment: @runway44 yes of course, my mistake (let's just say it was a typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(\phi,\theta)=(x,y)$.

Then

$$\frac yx=\tan\theta$$ gives you $\theta$ (on the four quadrants). Next

$$\frac{\sin\phi}{1-\cos\phi}=\frac{2\sin\frac\phi2\cos\frac\phi2}{2\sin^2\frac\phi2}=\cot\frac\phi2=x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta.$$

gives you $\phi$.

Comment: As $(\theta,\phi)\mapsto(\theta\pm\pi,2\pi-\phi)$ preserves $f$, wlog $\cot\phi/2$ is positive (i.e. $\phi\in[0,\pi]$), in which case $\cot\phi/2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ doesn't require using $\theta$ to solve for $\phi$. (Of course then $y/x=\tan\theta$ has two solutions for $\theta$, but the correct one can be chosen using the signs of $x$ and $y$.)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment yet. But here is a hint to an algorithm:

Set $a=\frac{\sin\phi}{1-\cos\phi}$ and rewrite the fuction $f$ into $g(\theta,a)=(a\cos\theta,a\sin\theta)$. You want to recover the input variables. Assume you have $x$ and $y$ given such that $x=a\cos\theta$ and $y=a\sin\theta$. To recover $a$ you have $a^2=x^2+y^2$ where $x$ and $y$ are known and then when you have $a$ you can obtain $\theta$ from $\tan\theta=\frac{y}{x}$. Further when you have $a$ you also recover $\phi$ from $a=\frac{\sin\phi}{1-\cos\phi}$ by use of some numerical solver. (You can build one yourself, a Newton solver).

Maybe someone here knows an analytic solution to obtain $\phi$?

Comment: Also worth mentioning that $\displaystyle \frac{\sin\phi}{1-\cos\phi}=\cot\frac{\phi}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Could you please elaborate a little more? I have made a try but this problem reach the limits of my knowledge.

Comment: A numerical solver is unnecessary.